# soap web service Endpoint publish

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I am implementing some soap based web-services, and I have some confusion on publishing the wsdl.

Piece of code:

```
    public class HelloWorldPublisher{  
          public static void main(String[] args) {  
             Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:9999/ws/hello", new HelloWorldImpl());  
         }  
    }
```

Now, when I ran this, it generated WSDL, and I could access it using link:

```
http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl
```

How is this possible? There is no server listening on port 9999 and still I was able to get the wsdl.

Any clarification would be great.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are using is RPC style of JAX-WS. Once you do `Endpoint.publish` java uses by default a light-weight HTTP server implementation that is included in java development kit. It uses an embedded container which is something running inside the same JVM. Try to open source code of `Endpoint.publish`

Comment: Yes I am using the RPC style. @SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)